# Reporting of form 1042-S

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, 401k

I am a US citizen living in Australia, 61 and made a small withdrawal from my 401K which they deducted 30% for tax.

I received  a 1042-S form from my 401k company for a withdrawal I made. DO I file the 1042-s with my 1040 or do I transfer it to a 1099-MISC and then report it. I would assume too that I report the income on line 21? Can I claim back the tax on my 1040?